# Connection pool in Envoy proxy

Tags: redis, proxy, connection-pooling, envoyproxy

I have configurated Envoy to be my proxy to the redis database, but I'm struggling at the connection pool option which is the most important thing that I need right now.
the following file shows the configurations:

```
admin:
  access_log_path: /tmp/admin_access.log
  address:
    socket_address:
      protocol: TCP
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 1936
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - name: redis_listener
    address:
      socket_address:
        protocol: TCP
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 1999
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.connection_limit
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.connection_limit.v3.ConnectionLimit
          stat_prefix: limited_connections
          max_connections: 3
          delay: 10s    
      - name: envoy.filters.network.redis_proxy
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.redis_proxy.v3.RedisProxy
          stat_prefix: redis_proxy
          settings:
            op_timeout: 5s
            enable_redirection: true
          prefix_routes:
            catch_all_route:
              cluster: redis_cluster
  clusters:
  - name: redis_cluster
    type: STRICT_DNS
    dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
    typed_extension_protocol_options:
      extensions.upstreams.tcp.generic.v3.GenericConnectionPoolProto:
        "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.upstreams.tcp.generic.v3.GenericConnectionPoolProto
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: redis_cluster
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: my-redis
                port_value: 6379
```

when running the server i got this message:

```
Didn't find a registered network or http filter or protocol options implementation for name: 'extensions.upstreams.tcp.generic.v3.GenericConnectionPoolProto'
```

In the official documentation, there is no options shown, may you help please with this issue.
Thank you,

Comment: As far as I understand, the `extensions.upstreams.tcp.generic.v3.GenericConnectionPoolProto` class can work only with HTTP connections, but Redis uses bare TCP.